# PHP recursive file system scan via Ajax too slow (need to checkpoint and resume)

Tags: php, ajax, recursion

I am using ZipArchive, PharData, PCLZip libs under the hood and trying to archive a file system path recursively and include a db dump.  The solution works, but takes too long if there's many files and/or large files.  On a dedicated host I can increase time limit/max execution time but I need a more generic solution.  So I opted to use client side ajax requests and break up the code into stages.  However the "archive" stage needs multiple calls over and over if a "continue" state is required because it didn't finish it's processing so the number of calls can be N and it returns status code 100 for continue or 200 for success/complete.  Between each add to archive file I check elapsed time and opt to kick back if I'm getting to close to the max execution time, sometimes it seems to bottlekneck I guess on large files or something where addFile to archive takes too long and I can't check and kick out yet.  So there's two cases such as a timeout and a manual kick out if getting to close to a timeout.

In PHP the script just times out, and if browser exit or JS calls abort I believe the PHP script still executes so I don't think I can do a JS quit on the script either.  In PHP I am using DirectoryIterator and RecursiveIteratorIterator and a custom FilterIterator.  I was hoping to just checkpoint these objects to disk or on resume seek them to the appropriate spot to resume on a subsequent ajax call but not sure if that's possible.  Serialize doesn't do anything and I'm only getting expected results from the DirectoryIterator seek operation not the RecursiveIteratorIterator that encapsulates it.

What is the best way to call a PHP function from ajax, checkpoint it's state, and resume on a subsequent ajax call when using iterators and recursively zipping files/dirs of a given path?  If I run into large files or other scenarios I'm guaranteed to timeout because I can't write logic checks if I'm in the middle of processing a large file.  I was looking at threads but doesn't seem portable or practical on shared hosting environments.  Ideally I'd just like to store state somewhere (db probably) and on a continue or timeout just resume and even if I'm off by a couple files I can just check if file is in the archive, just seems like too much overhead if I re-process all files/folders and check if they are in the archive just to get back to the resume point because I'm recursively re-scanning everything each time which is inefficient.

I'm trying a few coding solutions with no luck, any guidelines would be great and I can post code for a POC.

This is mainly an ajax/client and long running php task question, any help or guidence would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to come up with a workaround for hosts where safe_mode is enabled?  You can always reset or modify the execution times as long as safe_mode isn't in effect.  Otherwise, sharing session values that Ajax can update and the main script checks might be a way to go.  Just make sure to call session_write_close where appropriate so a background script doesn't block the ajax calls.  Also, keep in mind that if you add to a zip archive, and then close it, subsequent calls to add a file will make a copy of the entire zip file, so you're gonna have a ton of wasted disk IO here.

Comment: One script should be responsible for adding a series of files/dirs and then closing it (or timing out and the handle is closed) then a subsequent call not in parallel but one after the other.  So it's not a bunch of ajax requests running at the same time but after each other to avoid the script croaking and yes safe mode is a key issue.  I'm also having issues "resuming" a recursive iterator iterator, so wasting a ton of time re-scanning the entire directory structure to get to my resume point so the script is very slow/inneficient.